# Unity - On Custom Editor Update Event

Tags: unity, c#, scriptable-object

The following code is a snippet of how I'm auto-updating an object whenever a setting changes in the inspector window (for a scriptable object). It's currently not working, but It will work if I put the two lines `Editor editor...` and `editor.OnIns...` inside the `using` block. I'm confused on why this is.

```
    public void DrawSettingsEditor(Object settings, System.Action onSettingsUpdate)
    {
        Editor editor = CreateEditor(settings);
        editor.OnInspectorGUI();

        using (var check = new EditorGUI.ChangeCheckScope())
        {
            if (check.changed)
            {
                onSettingsUpdate();
            }
        }
    }
```

See https://pastebin.com/d0NumWZv for all the code for this class.

Comment: This seems to follow pretty directly from [the documented example of how to use ChangeCheckScope](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorGUI.ChangeCheckScope.html). Can you clarify, why would you expect this to work differently?

Comment: Oh looks like I didn't read the docs. I was following from a tutorial that used this code block. Thanks.

Comment: In future, when you have a question about how an API works, please start by consulting that API's documentation first. It will save you time.